# Picasso Image Loading After 10 Button clicks

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

The images from the internet using the Picasso libery are loading **after I click ten times** on the button. I also don't have an error so I really don't know what to do. So how can I show the image in one second after I click on the button.

Already got the Internet permission in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int a;
ImageView ivImageFromUrl;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ivImageFromUrl=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_image_from_url);
}

public void buttonOnClick(View v)  {
    // do something when the button is clicked
    Button button = (Button) v;

    a = (int) (Math.random() * 5);

    switch (a) {
        case 1:
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/crountch/one-piece-jolly-roger/72/Luffys-flag-2-icon.png").into(ivImageFromUrl);
          break;
        case 2:
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://i40.tinypic.com/2i8xait.jpg").into(ivImageFromUrl);
            break;
        case 3:
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://i41.tinypic.com/2i8xahh.jpg").into(ivImageFromUrl);
            break;
        case 4:
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://i42.tinypic.com/2i8xahk.jpg").into(ivImageFromUrl);
            break;
        case 5:
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://i40.tinypic.com/2i8xagp.jpg").into(ivImageFromUrl);
            break;
    }
 }
}
```

XML code

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Image text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="82dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Image"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/iv_image_from_url"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginBottom="106dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: is it really 10 clicks all the time?  I think a will take on values 0,1,2,3,4 not 1,2,3,4,5 so i could see you missing some clicks due to that.

Answer (score 0):

You have added a View object to method that isn't being called so it has no reference. I am unsure how it's working at all.

Your best bet would be to create the button separate and set an onClickListener to it and move the method code into the OnClick method.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //your code here
                a = (int) (Math.random() * 5);//and so on
            }
        });
```